# How can I display php in a tpl file?

Tags: php, task-parallel-library

How can I display php in ktools .tpl file.  I tried `{php}echo'test';{/php}` but it did not work.  I also tried `<? echo'test';?>` and `[php]echo'test';[/php]...` none of them worked.  Why is this not working?

Comment: I am using ktools photostore

Answer (score 0):

You need to display `test` or `echo 'test';`?

For second variant try `<pre>echo 'test';</pre>`